# two metrics on X such that lim d1(xn,x)=0 <=> lim d2(xn,x)=0, does it imply the identity of the two induced topologies?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on $X$
For all $x_n, x$ from $X$ it holds:
$$\lim d_1(x_n,x)=0 \iff \lim d_2(x_n,x)=0$$

Does it imply that the topology induced by $d_1$ is the same as the topology induced by $d_2$?

For example:
I have two definition of metric for compact convergence.
$X=C(IR,E)$ all continuous functions from $IR$ to $E$, where $E$ is a metric space with metric $q$

$d_1(f,g)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} * \sup \{q(f(x),g(x)) :x \in [0, i] \} $

$d_2(f,g)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \min \{2^{-i}, sup(q(f(x),g(x)) : x\in [0, i]) \} $

$\lim d_1(f_n,f)=0 \iff$ For all compact subset $K$ of $X$: $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $K \iff
\lim d_2(f_n,f)=0$.

Do these two metrics induce the same topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two topologies are equivalent since they have the same closed subsets. since a subset $C$ of a metric space $X$ is closed if and only if for every sequence $(x_n), x_n\in C$ such that $\lim_nx_n=x, x\in C$.

Comment: oh, how stupid I am, not even came to this obvious idea...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try to show that the identity map $\operatorname{Id}_X\colon (X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is continuous (and also the inverse).

(Use the definition that a function $f\colon X \to Y$ is continuous between metric spaces if and only if for all convergent sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$, we have $f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n)$.)

Comment: thank you too.  Your argument is also very helpful to me.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I would choose Arstide's answer as his answer is a bit earlier.